# Vim 8.2 says unwritten changes if I change netrw display views

Tags: netrw

I recently upgraded to Vim 8.2 (I don't recall what the last version was).  When I open a buffer to display the contents of a folder, it uses `netrw`, which I've enjoyed for years.  Now, if I use `netrw`'s `a` command to change the view (e.g., to display dot files in addition to visible files) and try to quit using `:q`, Vim complains about unwritten changes:

```
E37: No write since last change
E162: No write since last change for buffer the/folder/path
```

It doesn't *always* happen, but I've seen it quite a number of times since upgrading.  The exact version of Vim is:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 13 2022 22:15:51)
Included patches: 1-4372
Modified by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
Compiled by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
Huge version without GUI.
```

Before upgrading, I never saw such behaviour before.  I also do *not* see this behaviour in Vim 8.1, to which I have access on a Ubuntu VM:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep 19 2022 04:59:57)
Included patches: 1-2269, 3612, 3625, 3669, 3741
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.
```

I know that I can forcibly quit using `:q!`, but I think that it is unsafe to get into the habit of using that routinely.

Does anyone else see this on the above version?  Is there a quick fix?

Comment: Would be worth looking at patches between those versions, or patches from the buggy version to now, which touch the netrw code (to see if a bug or fix was introduced). `git log` with pathspecs and the appropriate dotted range of tags should do it.

Comment: Thank, Ben.  However, I'm not from a development background and am unfamiliar with git.

Comment: I see the same issue with NVIM v0.8.2